# 'Drupal\user\EntityOwnerTrait' not found

Tags: 8

I upgraded from 8.6.15 to 8.7.0 and now my page will not load.  I've searched for the error I'm getting (see below) but the results do not seem to apply to my situation.

I'm using installatron from my host provider for install and update.  Here's the error I am getting:

> PHP Fatal error:  Trait 'Drupal\user\EntityOwnerTrait' not found in /[deleted for brevity]/core/modules/node/src/Entity/Node.php on line 86

I'm not using Drush (although, maybe installatron is?) and need andy advice for getting my site back up.

Thanks

Comment: You need to run database updates somehow. Can you access /user or /admin? Can you find out if your server or project has Drush installed and run `drush updb` from it?

Comment: Thanks leymannx.  I'm not able to access /user or /admin or /update.php without getting this error.  I enabled SSH on the server using the cPanel tools, and tried to log in to the server to use Drush, but I get a message "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer".  Support says they can reach it just fine with SSH and could not offer any additional support.